# Pass data to jQuery modal and open it then

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, jquery-events

I have a list of items and each item includes the option to add a new comment. So I have this button where I can show the modal to enter a new comment for a specific item. The unique identifier for each item is it's commissionNumber:

```
    @foreach (var item in listofentities) 
    {
    
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="commentDialogOpener_@item.CommissionNumber" onclick="OpenCommentModal(e)" data-id="@item.CommissionNumber"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
    }

    
    <div id="newCommentDialog" title="New Comment">
        <form id="commentForm" asp-action="AddComment">
           <input type="hidden" id="commissionNumber" name="commissionNumber"/>
           <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;"></textarea>
           <label id="EmptyTextAreaWarningLabel" hidden style="color: red;">Please enter a comment</label>
        </form>
    </div>
```

To open that `DIV` for entering the new comment, I use the `onclick`-method with the link provided for every item. I try to hand over the `data-id` field of the link to the hidden variable in my new comment modal. Here's the JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {           

        $(function () {
            $("#newCommentDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        if ($("#comment").val() == null || $("#comment").val().trim() == '') {
                            // textarea is empty
                            $("#EmptyTextAreaWarningLabel").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("commentForm").submit();
                        }


                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });

    function OpenCommentModal(e)
    {
        alert(e.Value);
        $('#commissionNumber').val() = ??
        $("#newCommentDialog").dialog("open");
    }
```

And that's where I'm stuck. I don't know how pass the event data to the OpenCommentModal function. I need to read that ID of the  element where the click comes from to pass the value behind @item.commissonNumber to the hidden variable in the modal. I'm somehow lost here because I don't know where to get that done. Intellisense doesn't provide me with any help about the event element of JS...

Only error message I get is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

which refers to the parameter e that I passed with the `onclick`-routine

Comment: try `OpenCommentModal(this)`, note that `<a>` element has no value, you can get its associated data by getting attribute value or data value, either natively or using jQuery

Comment: That removes the error I received and I can now open the modal with every items' button. Will try to pass forward the data now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the id into your click function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="commentDialogOpener_@item.CommissionNumber" onclick="OpenCommentModal(this.id)" data-id="@item.CommissionNumber"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

In your click function you can use your id and store it in a data property with the name "id" for example.

```
 function OpenCommentModal(id)
 {
     $("#newCommentDialog").data("id", id).dialog("open");
 }
```

In your dialog code you can now read it out like this:

```
 $('#newCommentDialog').data("id");
```